# Transfer Aegir site to LAMP

Tags: 7, aegir

**Can anyone please advice me on how to move a Drupal 7 site from Aegir to a LAMP stack?**

I've been handed the emergency project of moving a site to a new hosting. Ordinarily, that would be easy enough until I realise the site is loosing it's hosting in a matter of days, **settings.php** is not in the **sites/default** directory nor is the **files** directory. The structure is not standard D7 at all.

I later realised the site is currently hosted on Aegir which admittedly I know nothing about but I wonder if Aegir created the non standard structure. I used the **tree** command to show the structure below:

```
tree project/sites/ -L 2
core-1.23/sites/
|-- all
|   |-- drush
|   |-- libraries
|   |-- modules
|   |-- README.txt
|   `-- themes
|-- default
|   `-- default.settings.php
|-- example.sites.php
|-- sites.php
`-- www.clientsite.com
    |-- drushrc.php
    |-- email
    |-- files
    |-- googlef1245ba6b3c38a3c.hmtl
    |-- libraries
    |-- local.settings.php
    |-- modules
    |-- pdf
    |-- private
    |-- README.md
    |-- settings_.php
    |-- settings.php
    |-- themes
    `-- vendor
```

As you can see, the settings.php is in a sub-directory named after the actual live site, very unlike a vanilla Drupal 7 code structure.

I admit I am stymied by this.

Can anyone tell me if this is how Aegir layout the Drupal structure and **how I can move this to a more traditional D7 structure** ???

Comment: Unless it changed since I used it a few years back, Aegir uses a standard multisite approach, which is the structure you're seeing. You don't really need to move it to a "traditional" structure, it'll work just fine as-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

> `settings.php` is not in the `sites/default` directory nor is the `files` directory. The structure is not standard D7 at all.

That's incorrect.  From the [Aegir documentation](https://docs.aegirproject.org/usage/sites/#multisite):

> Aegir installs sites on a platform, which means it places the site directory in `/var/aegir/platforms/<your_platform>/sites/<yoursite.com>`. Many sites can all be installed alongside each other inside a platform's 'sites' directory. This is a standard, built-in Drupal feature known as 'multisite', and it is not unique to Aegir.

...and [the official Drupal documentation on multisite](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multisite/drupal-8-multisite):

> It should be noted, however, that using the [Aegir hosting system](https://www.aegirproject.org/) is preferred.  It does all of the heavy lifting for you using secure best practices including automatically configuring virtual hosts for both Apache and Nginx, adding HTTPS support, running Composer commands, etc.  See [the documentation for setting up a "platform"](https://docs.aegirproject.org/usage/platforms/), Aegir-speak for a multisite codebase.

So when you ask, *how I can move this to a more traditional D7 structure?*, the correct answer is that you can't.  Besides following Drupal standards, Aegir additionally follows best practices for security (e.g. setting secure file permissions) and sustainability (point-and-click upgrades of multiple sites at once).  So you're far better off hosting Drupal sites with Aegir than the "traditional" way.

My recommendation would therefore be to set up a new Aegir instance elsewhere, and then [remotely import the sites](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_remote_import) before the older instance is decommissioned.  If you're running a LAMP stack yourself, there are very few reasons why you shouldn't be running Aegir for multi-site Drupal.