# Aegir Drupal 7 Website migration

Tags: migrations, aegir

I need desperately help.
I clarify that I am not a developer but I have just basic knowledge of Drupal and Aegir.
Few years ago a developer guy installed Aegir on VPS (Hostwind) and Drupal.
Now Hostwind decided to interrupt this service and I have to migrate.

My question is: what is best option to migrate?

Should I migrate Drupal and Aegir or just Drupal (without Aegir)? Is it possible to migrate only Drupal?

As test can install Aegir locally on Mac using MAMP to test if I am doing correctly?

Thank you

Comment: There are a lot of questions in this forum already about Aegir, for example, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283619/transfer-aegir-site-to-lamp

Comment: Yes I saw it. From that answer I understood that if want to migrate a Drupal website installed under Aegir to another host I need Aegir also in the new host. Is that correct?

Comment: The question is almost identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a Drupal site somewhere without Aegir.  However, as an application life-cycle manager (ALM) platform as a service (PaaS), Aegir adds extra value (e.g. monitoring, backups, rollback on upgrades, etc.)

The value of Aegir increases with the number of sites hosted.  The selling point for me is that you can upgrade 200 sites at once with a single button click.  But if you only have one site, it may not be worth it.  You have to weigh the benefits that Aegir provides (see [the docs](https://docs.aegirproject.org/)) vs. the added maintenance of maintaining Aegir itself.

That is, if you really want to run your own platform as a service (PaaS).  Other options are [hosted Aegir](https://omega8.cc/) (if you really like it) or finding a Drupal hosting company which offers their own proprietary PaaS for running Drupal.  (I'll leave this search as an exercise to the reader. Ask good questions like: [Does your Drupal hosting company lack native Composer support?](https://consensus.enterprises/blog/drupal-hosting-company-lacking-composer-support/))

Obviously, you can forget about the PaaS, and just run the Drupal site yourself if you want to self host.

If you'd like to try Aegir locally, have a look at the [Aegir Development VM](https://gitlab.com/aegir/aegir-dev-vm).

Comment: I totally agree that Aegir can be worthy. The only issue is that I am not sure if I have the skills to use it. I may try a local version and see how it goes.

Comment: regarding that particular website that now is under Aegir I tried to extract and run without Aegir and it didn't work. The organisation of the folder with Aegir and without Aegir are different.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @Gilles9999 If you have a budget for some consulting help and it's not urgent, we may be able to help.  We're a bit busy, but might be able to find some time soon.  If you're interested, please use [our contact form](https://consensus.enterprises/#contact).